# Discord bot python embed message reaction

Tags: python, discord.py

My target is to make bot react to this embed message and also continue when someone reacts

```py
@client.event 
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author == client.user:
      return
    if ctx.content.startswith('.summon'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=":crossed_swords:I have been summoned:crossed_swords:", description="to proceed select lvl of your enemy", color=0x00ff00)
        embed.add_field(name="Difficulty level :one:", value="suitable for quick xp, or single take down", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Difficulty level :two:", value="sigher level enemy, with lots of hp and sweet reward", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Difficulty level :three:", value="almost if not impossible enemy, strongest of them all, suitable only for raids", inline=False)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Hey Martin, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to narrow it down to *a specific programming question*. SO is not a code-writing service, and questions need to focus on *one* problem only. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

`ctx.channel.send()` returns the message sent. If you save that in a variable, you will be able to use the [add_reaction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ohgtglx6SRM&ab_channel=LeagueofLegends) method to add reactions. It takes a unicode string or emoji as parameter.

To check whether a user reacts, the [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) method can be used to wait for a user to add a reaction, and make the bot reply accordingly.

I have included a small example below, though the documentation I linked gives you all the information you need.

The Discord.py library has it's own Discord server, where you can always ask questions, here's the link: https://discord.gg/dpy

```py
@client.event 
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author == client.user:
      return
    if ctx.content.startswith('.summon'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=":crossed_swords:I have been summoned:crossed_swords:", description="to proceed select lvl of your enemy", color=0x00ff00)
        embed.add_field(name="Difficulty level :one:", value="suitable for quick xp, or single take down", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Difficulty level :two:", value="sigher level enemy, with lots of hp and sweet reward", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Difficulty level :three:", value="almost if not impossible enemy, strongest of them all, suitable only for raids", inline=False)
        
        # Saving the sent message in a variable here.
        message = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
        await message.add_reaction('\U0001f534')
     
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '\U0001f534'

       try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            # Do whatever if the user did not react within 60 seconds.
            await ctx.channel.send('')
        else:
            # If users reacted in time, you can check which reaction they
            # pressed by checking it against str(reaction.emoji)
            await ctx.channel.send('')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you're needing to answer multiple questions in the same answer (i.e. "How do I react to a message I sent?" and "How do I wait for a reaction from another user"), then you should flag the post as "Needs More Focus". Answering these questions is rarely of value to the site, it's more beneficial to have these questions closed (or edited, but once this question focuses on *one* problem, it will certainly be a duplicate of another question)

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs Thank you for pointing me out on that, will start doing so!